# How to Defend against the Stefano build?

Tags: starcraft-2

As a Protoss how do I defend against the Stefano style build that consists of making three very early bases and pushing once there is a huge number of roaches, sometimes maxed out, at a very early point in the game? It is very deadly to protoss and I don't know how they can even think of stopping it.

Comment: This is one of the easiest builds to prevent, because it relies on P being passive for 11 minutes. It's amazing how far behind you can put the Z player by a little harassment.

Comment: Well, I should have phrased this question better. I play as zerg and I haven't seen protoss being able to stop it. Early harassment is very easy to stop by simply pumping out some lings instead of drones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean the 11-minute max-roach thing, the latest Day[9] daily covers exactly that: http://day9.tv/d9d472/

It basically boils down to lots of sentries to slice his army into manageable pieces.

Comment: I have watched that daily, but it doesn't describe exactly how to defend against it. It doesn't cover it in-depth. I was hoping to find a detailed answer on ways to stop the push.

Comment: There is no "exactly" to any strategy.

Comment: I didn't mean to say "exact" I mean't more detailed.

Comment: Maybe you'd like to upload a replay of you loosing to this strategy. Then, people could point out your shortcomings. It really just boils down to sentries, immortals, and mad micro skills. I suggest you make it to gold in the Psionic Assault challenge if you have trouble with your sentry control.

Answer (score 2):

Your core units to defend it are Sentries and Immortals which must be kept alive at any cost. You also need to keep your third alive which is the hardest part since the attack comes right when you are about to really establish it.

Basically you wait for the opponent to come through any choke point near the natural or the third, forcefield ~1/3 of his army and crush it with your stalker/immortal forces. Then you forcefield the next chunk until you max out on stalkers and immortals and then you just go kill him.

Void Rays are another option that MC seems to prefer but it is a lot riskier since he can drown you in more roaches than your Void Rays can kill in time, which is also called the Mondragon-Counter.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The three base roach attack wins by shutting down your third, then killing you. If you haven't got a third, but have a highly defensible natural/main and don't move out until you are 3/3 with a 200/200 death ball you should be able to beat it. A maxed Collossus/Archon/Immortal/Sentry/Stalker army does hideous damage to roach/ling maxed armies. Roaches are very supply inefficient.

Remember that he's spending all his gas on roaches, he won't have a spire or infestation pit and so getting high level tech is going to take a while.

Comment: I was just looking over old questions and realized how much I have learned since then, so i'd like to point out that if a protoss stays on one base the zerg will take a few more bases, continue tech and since the zerg is maxed out he will start teching. Roaches don't take much gas and once zerg is maxed, he will have nothing better to do but to spine up, drone, tech, and expand.